# How to seperate out ERROR FILE from Correct file using SSIS and archive them

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a scenario where there are two source file ABC.txt and DEF.txt. i want to make sure that if any files are present in that folder with naming convention as ABC.txt, it has to be moved to the different folder prior to loading to the SQL server, and the other (incorrect file) should be moved to a error log folder (separate folder). Can someone advice what task would i use to do that. i tried it using File system task but it just allow you to move or copy files from one location to other prior to loading the file.can someone advice how to i copy that incorrect file to the different folder ( error log folder)?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a bat file.

```
move ABC.txt /directory
```

and after

```
xcopy "source" "destination_err\" /exclude:%temp%\ABC.txt /y
```

or you can use robocopy command in bat file, this is the command with parameters http://itsvista.com/2007/03/robocopy/